# Compiling using gcc 3.2.3 on RHE 5.3

Tags: c++, gcc, redhat

Some work I'm doing for a client requires me to build using a very old version of gcc on Red Hat Enterprise. We recently shifted from 4.x to 5.3 and I'm hitting some compile errors when I try to build simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following:

```
bash-3.2$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp
In file included from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/stl_alloc.h:90,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/memory:55,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/string:48,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/localefwd.h:49,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/ios:48,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/ostream:45,
                 from /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/iostream:45,
                 from hello.cpp:1:
/opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/stl_threads.h: In 
   constructor `std::_Refcount_Base::_Refcount_Base(unsigned int)':
/opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/stl_threads.h:74: error: `
   __LOCK_INITIALIZER' undeclared (first use this function)
/opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/include/c++/3.2.3/bits/stl_threads.h:74: error: (Each
   undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears 
   in.)
```

`__LOCK_INITIALIZER` is a pthreads macro, but clearly I'm not using it directly here. Has anyone seen this kind of problem before or can offer any possible suggestions as tyo why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of GCC installed on you machine?

Comment: PS. Note you should be using g++ (not gcc) to compile C++ code with (g++ is the C++ frontend to GCC)

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes we do have more than one version of GCC on this box. All appear to be in versioned directories (see path in error message) and I am using g++ directly.

Comment: What is the output of g++ --version does it match the directory structure above?

Comment: @Robin Welch: PS. When replying to a comment use @ (see beginning of line for example). This way the person you are replying to gets informed that they have a reply.

Comment: @Martin York: Thanks for that. The problem is apparently down to the installation of gcc323 which, on top of 5.3, does not work very well in the client's environment (headers get 'fixed' incorrectly.) They have a work around of sorts provided I stick to a limited build environment. It's either that or move to gcc4x - which frankly, I would much rather do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to? In particular gcc relies on libgcc* and libstdc++* (although if you've statically linked it that shouldn't be an issue). If it is an issue try setting your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /opt/ext/gcc-3.2.3.34rh/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH.